# Параметры конструктора

Tags: java, конструктор, инициализация, параметры

1.

```
public class TestEmployee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "larry";
        Employee harry = new Employee(name);
    }
}
class Employee {
    String name;
    public Employee(String n) {
        name = n;
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }
}
```

2.

```
public class TestEmployee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "larry";
        Employee harry = new Employee(name);
    }
}
class Employee {
    String name;
    public Employee(String name) {
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }
}
```

Не могу понять простую вещь. При создании объектов в круглых скобках указываются аргументы. В зависимости от этих аргументов выбирается нужный конструктор. В учебнике приведен пример как на первом листинге. Зачем указывать некую ссылку `n`, когда можно просто написать `name` и вызовется тот же конструктор?

Comment: Вам придется тогда так написать. `public Employee (String name) { this.name = name; }` Будет просто совпадение имен и аргумент "закроет" собой Name неявного аргумента. Придется this указать.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что после этой записи `{ this.name = name. }` ссылка `name` будет ссылаться на поле экземпляра `String name`. Но зачем это нужно, если здесь `public Employee(String name)` уже указывается тип этой ссылки?

Comment: @user31238 Компилятор в состоянии отличить конструкцию `name = name` корректно, `this` указывается больше для человека, чтобы ему было понятнее.

Comment: @pavlofff читабельность - наше все

Comment: @KojerDefor аргумент присваевается полю класса, чтобы он был доступен везде в классе, а не только в том конструкторе, в который передан (переменная, переданая через конструктор будет доступна только внутри конструктора. Подробнее читайте о областях видимости переменных в Java). Соответственно, если вам не нужно это значение за пределами конструктора, то нет нужды присваивать его полю класса.

Comment: @pavlofff Без `this.` конструкция `name = name;` бессмысленна, это присваивание переменной самой себе. Компилятор не будет догадываться, что имелось в виду присвоение полю.

Comment: @Roman проверил. Да, вы правы, странно, но я был уверен в обратном.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точное название параметра конструктора (в отличие от типа) не играет роли. Во втором листинге, значение, переданное в параметре name, не будет записано в поле объекта Employee. Добавьте вызов отображения значения поля `name` после создания экземпляров класса в каждом случае, например, для второго случая:

```
public class TestEmployee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "larry";
        Employee harry = new Employee(name);
        System.out.println(harry.name);
    }
}
class Employee {
    String name;
    public Employee(String name) {
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы визуально отличить название параметра и название поля класса, параметр назвали `n`, его могли также назвать и `name`, но тогда визуально было бы сложнее отличить, где что. В любом случае, компилятор бы успешно разобрал такую конструкцию и скомпилировал класс.

Главное, что вы должны понять из этого примера: **просто называя параметр конструктора как и поле класса, не добъетесь автоматического присвоения значений!**

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ.

Comment: На самом деле, здесь все дело в областях видимости переменных в Java, которая распространяется только до фигурных скобок, где эта переменная определена - этим все и объясняется

Answer (score 3):

В объявлении конструктора этого класса

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    public Employee(String name) {
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }
}
```

параметр конструктора `name` - это локальная переменная конструктора, которая скрывает одноименное поле класса. Это поле конструктором не инициализируется, поэтому поле класса `name` будет иметь значение `null`. В этом случае бессмысленно указаывать параметр у конструктора. Правильно было бы записать

```
    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }
```

Если вам еще надо определить конструктор по умолчанию, то есть конструктор, который вызывается без аргументов, то, например, вы можете записать

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("constructor with parameter");
    }
    public Employee() {
        this.name = "";
        System.out.println("default constructor");
    }
}
```